# PHP if and else statement not working properly

Tags: php

im trying to create a script that generates a number and depending on the number generated it prints something specific but it's not working properly, Heres the code:

```
<?php
  for($zz = 1; $zz <= 20; $zz++) {
    $rangen = rand(1,100);
    $a = (1 <= 0) && (0 <= 7);
    $b = (8 <= 0) && (0 <= 17);
    echo ("<br>".$rangen . "<br>");
    if($a) {
        echo "a";
    } elseif ($b) {
        echo "b";
    } else {
        echo "c";
    }
  }
?>
```

The error is that it keeps printing "c" no matter what the number is.

If anyone could help that would be great, thanks.

Comment: $a and $b value is** false** every time  so its go to else and print c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions are all wrong. Your comparing the same numbers and never using $rangen, this is why you obtain the same result each time.

1 <= 0 and 8 <= 0 will always return false which is why you always go to the else statement.

Comment: No problem. As long as you got the answer you needed